# How to format the XML schema validation error message in Java?

Tags: java, xml, validation, domparser, saxparseexception

I want the default error messages printed when validating a xml file against it's schema to be set in a specific format.

1. I do not want the **schema error codes** to be included in the error message. i.e, cvc-complex-type-2-4-b,  cvc-mininclusive-valid etc.,
2. I do not want the **namespace** to be printed in the error messages.  e.g, One of '{"http://sample.org/xml_schema":schema_version}' is expected.
   Note - The XML and XSD use Namespaces.

For example,

Default error message :

> "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'report_version'. One of '{"http://sample.org/xml_schema":schema_version}' is expected."

Expected error message :

> "Invalid content was found starting with element 'report_version'. One of '{schema_version}' is expected."

Code :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

try {
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema    = sf.newSchema(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sample_schema.xsd"));
    factory.setSchema(schema);

    DocumentBuilder builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException exception) {
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
            }
        });

    doc   = builder.parse(inputSource);
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

Let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Do you use a specific implementation or do you want this to be portable?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - I don't need it to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to override the Expception itself (besides maybe deriving from it and somehow override the throw function, but humm...). Because getMessage() returns a String (possibly null?) you can try to format it by yourself before printing.

There are two ':' so you can cut off everyting in front of the first ':', also you can throw everyting between " ": into the waste bin as far as the message you posted is concerned. Keeping this in mind I am not sure if ALL SaxParseException look like this, you should give it a try.

Idea-Set:

```
StringBuilder b = exception.getMessage();
b.delete(0, b.indexOf(":"));
b.replace(b.indexOf("{"), b.indexOf("":"), "{"); (you maybe must excape the " with \)
System.out.println(b.toString());
```

Hope this helps, feel free to ask.

Comment: The problem with this is that not all the error message have a schema error code (i.e, cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: etc., ) in the front. There are messages that don't have the error code in the front but may contain colons as part of the exception message. Therefore, I need to know that the text before the first colon is an error code, only then I can truncate the error code prefix and format the message.

Comment: Can you share your project on GH or something? Coz it is much easier then to help :) Or a running excerpt?